# Facing problem to importing csv file with bulk importer in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to load nodes and its relations from csv file using neo4j bulk importer my script like this

```
neo4j-admin import \
--id-type=string \
--nodes:AGENT="nodes_AGENT_C_20190610.csv" \
--nodes:CUSTOMER="nodes_CUSTOMER_C_20190610.csv" \
--relationships:CASHOUT="relcashoutTest-header.csv,relcashoutTest.csv"
```

and my csv file like this for relationship files

```
:TYPE,:START_ID(CUSTOMER),:END_ID(AGENT),TXNID:string,TIMESTAMP:datetime,AMOUNT:int,CHANNEL
```

Here TYPE indicates the column named RELATIONSHIP
and my relational csv file look like this

```
CASHOUT,abc,xyz,6C19MX7DXL,2019-03-01T11:02:55,40,charge
CASHOUT,pqr,jkl,6C19MX7E2V,2019-03-01T11:02:57,10,charge
```

after running my import.sh script I am getting bellow error
**unexpected error: Group 'CUSTOMER' not found. Available groups are: []**

I have gone through the document but didn't figure it out my mistakes. Any help will be appreciated neo4j version is 3.5.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:START_ID` and `:END_ID` fields can take an optional [ID space](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/import/file-header-format/#import-tool-id-spaces), as in `:START_ID(CUSTOMER)`.

But an **ID space** is *not* the same thing as a node **label**. In order for `:START_ID(CUSTOMER)` to work, one of your node CSV files (presumably the one for the `CUSTOMER` label) must specify, in its header, `:ID(CUSTOMER)` instead of just `:ID`. Doing so would associate the `CUSTOMER` ID space with the nodes created by that file, and you should no longer see that specific error.

You may also need to do something similar for the `AGENT` ID space.

*NOTE: If all your nodes have unique values in the `:ID` field (across CSV files), then you do not need to use ID spaces at all. In that case, your relationship file header can simply use `:START_ID` and `:END_ID` without any qualification.*